# Downloading from sourceforge (wait and redirect)

Tags: go, download, http-redirect

I have a dowload function like the following:

```
func Download(url, dir string) error {
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    filename := filepath.Base(url)
    filepath := path.Join(dir, filename)
    out, err := os.Create(filepath)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer out.Close()
    _, err = io.Copy(out, resp.Body)
    return err
}
```

But I do not get the file when I try to download from `Sourceforge` because it has a wait (countdown) and a redirect.

```
url := https://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/expat/expat-2.2.10.tar.xz"
Download(url, ".")
```

Is there any way to download from Sourceforge programatically?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do it:

```
package main

import (
   "net/http"
   "os"
   "path"
)

const (
s = "http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.2.10/expat-2.2.10.tar.xz"
)

func main() {
   r, e := http.Get(s)
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   defer r.Body.Close()
   f, e := os.Create(path.Base(s))
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   defer f.Close()
   f.ReadFrom(r.Body)
}
```

However, I have found SourceForge is not great for downloads, here is a mirror:

https://github.com/libexpat/libexpat/releases

Comment: Sorry steve, it does not work, file downloaded is not a tar.xz, its content is a html, because redirect did not work. So download fails

Answer (score 0):

Clearing all the headers for each redirect works. Replace first line of your function with:

```
client := &http.Client{}
client.CheckRedirect = func(req *http.Request, via []*http.Request) error {
    for k, _ := range req.Header {
        delete(req.Header, k)
    }
    return nil
}
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
resp, err := client.Do(req)
```

Tested with:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/procps-ng/files/Production/procps-ng-3.3.17.tar.xz
https://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/expat/expat-2.4.1.tar.xz

I had the same issue. Guys at #go-nuts helped me to solve this.

Another solution: https://play.golang.org/p/KuLr2c7beDA.